# Где найти комплекс инструментов "войти через ..."

Tags: javascript, html, css

На многих сайтах можно входить через другие сайты или социальные сети. Как это осуществить, есть ли готовые наборы сразу многих соц.сетей, что-бы не искать инструменты для каждой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- http://www.oneall.com/
- http://loginza.ru/
- http://ulogin.ru/
- http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/ - для тех кто хочет не зависеть от посредников

Comment: @mantigatos я выбрал ulogin.ru, а как сделать виджет такой на локале?

Answer (score 2):

[uLogin](http://ulogin.ru/) - достаточно будет?